# Modify Data Range Options in DateRange Component

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to know how can i modify the date range options in CDE DateRange Componenet. 
There are options like "Today", "Month to Date", "The previous month", etc. I want to remove 'The previous Month' and 'Specific Date' from the stream. 
Is there any way i can do this in preExecution?

Comment: Do you just want to remove these two fields from the stream? Are you asking about PDI or CDE? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi Nikhi, thanks for the reply. It's the date range component in CDE, and i just want to remove theses two fields in the menu for one dashboard.

Comment: Ok. I am not familiar with CDE much. I would suggest you to try Pentaho forum if nobody answers here.

Comment: as per my Knowledge, you will not able to do achieve it using pre-execution.
you have to do some customization for this on component level.